# T-SQL Merge Two Comma-Separated Columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, merge

I'm trying to merge one table into another (we'll call them Stage and Prod) that controls users and their permissions. My end result should be a single Prod table that has combined each userid's permissions from Stage into Prod. The issue I'm having though is that the tables were designed by an outside vendor and contain multiple pieces of information in one comma-delimited column.

Stage might look like below:

```
Userid     | Permissions
----------------------------------------------------------------
1          | schedule,upload,test,download,admin
2          | test,upload
3          | download
```

Prod:

```
Userid     | Permissions
----------------------------------------------------------------
1          | test,admin,schedule,download,upload
2          | admin
3          | download,upload
```

When they're merged, the userids should have their permissions from Stage, combined with those in Prod. However, tackling this when the permissions are a comma-delimited string has me at wit's end.

In the final result below, userid 1's permissions remain unchanged because they are the same in Stage as they are in Prod, merely in a different order.
Userid 2 had his Stage permissions added to his Prod since he did not have those permissions yet.
Userid 3 had his Prod permissions unchanged since his Stage permissions are already included.

Result:

```
Userid     | Permissions
----------------------------------------------------------------
1          | test,admin,schedule,download,upload
2          | admin,test,upload
3          | download,upload
```

Is there any way to do this? Hopefully this makes some sense, but if there's any more info that might help I'm happy to try to provide it. Thank you for any help at all.

Comment: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/04/21/sql-server-split-comma-separated-list-without-using-a-function/ to split them out into a normal list, union (union does the distinct) the results from two environments, and combine them back.  though why you would store data this way is beyond me.

Comment: Do you care what order they end up in? I agree with xQbert that if there's another way to store them that would be better. Also, if there's a predetermined list of possible permissions, there's an easier way to do this than splitting the strings.

Comment: @xQbert I definitely agree that there are better ways to store this data, unfortunately it's a vendor-constructed table whose schema we can't really change.

Comment: @DaveX The order they go in shouldn't matter and those permissions test, admin, schedule, download, upload are the only permissions. Thank you guys and all for your input, I'll give these a try and mark an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly enough, this was a topic of discussion on a [MSSQLTips blog](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4140/removing-duplicates-from-strings-in-sql-server/) by [Aaron Bertrand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61305/aaron-bertrand).  Borrowing his code you can create the `Numbers` table and string splitting/reassembling functions required to make the following work.  If you are planning on doing this often and are stuck with the schema you've shown, this is the way to go.

```
/*Create Test Data

create table StagePermissions (UserID int, [Permissions] nvarchar(max));
create table ProdPermissions (UserID int, [Permissions] nvarchar(max));

insert StagePermissions values
(1,'schedule,upload,test,download,admin'),
(2,'test,upload'),
(3,'download')

insert ProdPermissions values
(1,'test,admin,schedule,download,upload'),
(2,'admin'),
(3,'download,upload')
*/

select sp.UserID, dbo.ReassembleString(sp.Permissions+','+pp.Permissions,',',N'OriginalOrder') MergedPermissions
from StagePermissions sp
    join ProdPermissions pp on pp.UserID=sp.UserID
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking Steve's test data, but adding:

```
create table BothPermissions (UserID int, [Permissions] nvarchar(max));
```

This code will work with a fixed number of possible permissions.

```
DECLARE @XPermissions TABLE (
     UserID int
    ,XSchedule  BIT
    ,XUpload    BIT
    ,XTest      BIT
    ,XDownload  BIT
    ,XAdmin     BIT
    )

INSERT INTO @XPermissions
    SELECT
        ISNULL(sp.UserID,pp.UserID),
        CHARINDEX('schedule',sp.[Permissions]) + CHARINDEX('schedule',pp.[Permissions]),
        CHARINDEX('upload',sp.[Permissions]) + CHARINDEX('upload',pp.[Permissions]),
        CHARINDEX('test',sp.[Permissions]) + CHARINDEX('test',pp.[Permissions]),
        CHARINDEX('download',sp.[Permissions]) + CHARINDEX('download',pp.[Permissions]),
        CHARINDEX('admin',sp.[Permissions]) + CHARINDEX('admin',pp.[Permissions])

    FROM StagePermissions sp
        FULL JOIN ProdPermissions pp
            ON sp.UserID = pp.UserID

INSERT INTO BothPermissions
    SELECT
        UserID,
        CASE XSchedule WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE 'schedule  ' END +
        CASE XUpload WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE 'upload  ' END +
        CASE XTest WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE 'test  ' END +
        CASE XDownload WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE 'download  ' END +
        CASE XAdmin WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE 'admin' END
    FROM @XPermissions

UPDATE BothPermissions
    SET [Permissions] = REPLACE(RTRIM([Permissions]),'  ',', ')
```

Now, I was further curious about Steve's answer. I think it is the most robust solution here. However, I wondered how it would perform with a large dataset. I still don't know the answer because I haven't set up the tools necessary to use it. But here's a query that includes some random number generation to populate 10,000 records of each:

```
SELECT GETDATE()
DECLARE @StagePerms TABLE (
     UserID INT IDENTITY
    ,Perms  NVARCHAR(MAX)
    )

DECLARE @ProdPerms TABLE (
     UserID INT IDENTITY
    ,Perms  NVARCHAR(MAX)
    )

DECLARE @Counter INT = 0
DECLARE @XString NVARCHAR(MAX)

WHILE @Counter < 10000
    BEGIN
        SET @Counter += 1
            SET @XString = REPLACE(RTRIM(
                CASE ROUND(RAND()-.2,0) WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE 'test  ' END +
                CASE ROUND(RAND()-.2,0) WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE 'admin  ' END +
                CASE ROUND(RAND()-.2,0) WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE 'schedule  ' END +
                CASE ROUND(RAND()-.2,0) WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE 'download  ' END +
                CASE ROUND(RAND()-.2,0) WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE 'upload  ' END)
                ,'  ',', ') 
            INSERT INTO @StagePerms SELECT @XString
            SET @XString = REPLACE(RTRIM(
                CASE ROUND(RAND()-.2,0) WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE 'test  ' END +
                CASE ROUND(RAND()-.2,0) WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE 'admin  ' END +
                CASE ROUND(RAND()-.2,0) WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE 'schedule  ' END +
                CASE ROUND(RAND()-.2,0) WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE 'download  ' END +
                CASE ROUND(RAND()-.2,0) WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE 'upload  ' END)
                ,'  ',', ')
            INSERT INTO @ProdPerms SELECT @XString
    END

SELECT GETDATE()

DECLARE @BothPerms TABLE (
     UserID INT
    ,Perms  NVARCHAR(MAX)
    )

DECLARE @XPerms TABLE (
     UserID int
    ,XSchedule  BIT
    ,XUpload    BIT
    ,XTest      BIT
    ,XDownload  BIT
    ,XAdmin     BIT
    )

INSERT INTO @XPerms
    SELECT
        ISNULL(sp.UserID,pp.UserID),
        CHARINDEX('schedule',sp.Perms) + CHARINDEX('schedule',pp.Perms),
        CHARINDEX('upload',sp.Perms) + CHARINDEX('upload',pp.Perms),
        CHARINDEX('test',sp.Perms) + CHARINDEX('test',pp.Perms),
        CHARINDEX('download',sp.Perms) + CHARINDEX('download',pp.Perms),
        CHARINDEX('admin',sp.Perms) + CHARINDEX('admin',pp.Perms)

    FROM @StagePerms sp
        FULL JOIN @ProdPerms pp
            ON sp.UserID = pp.UserID

INSERT INTO @BothPerms
    SELECT
        UserID,
        CASE XTest WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE 'test  ' END +
        CASE XAdmin WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE 'admin  ' END +
        CASE XSchedule WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE 'schedule  ' END +
        CASE XDownload WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE 'download  ' END +
        CASE XUpload WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE 'upload  ' END

    FROM @XPerms

UPDATE @BothPerms
    SET Perms = REPLACE(RTRIM(Perms),'  ',', ')

SELECT * FROM @BothPerms

SELECT GETDATE()
```

The random number generation took less than a second; the rest took about 31 seconds. Steve, I'd be interested to see a comparison. Doesn't matter, obviously, if the data doesn't allow for my solution. And I'm sure there's a sweet spot somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Please make use of the below query. Its working fine in SQL Server 2012.

```
DECLARE @Stage TABLE (Userid int, Permission Varchar (8000))
DECLARE @Prod TABLE (Userid int, Permission Varchar (8000))
DECLARE @temp TABLE (Userid int, Permission Varchar (8000))

INSERT @Stage
(Userid,Permission)
VALUES
(1,'schedule,upload,test,download,admin'),
(2,'test,upload'),
(3,'download')

INSERT @Prod
(Userid,Permission)
VALUES
(1,'test,admin,schedule,download,upload'),
(2,'admin'),
(3,'download,upload')
-- Execution Part
INSERT INTO @temp
(Userid,Permission)
(
    SELECT A.Userid AS Userid,Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Permission FROM  
    (SELECT Userid,CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(Permission, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Permission FROM @Stage A) AS A 
    CROSS APPLY Permission.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
    UNION
    SELECT A.Userid AS Userid,Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Permission FROM  
    (SELECT Userid,CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(Permission, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Permission FROM @Prod A) AS A 
    CROSS APPLY Permission.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
)

SELECT Userid, Permission = 
        STUFF((SELECT ', ' + Permission
               FROM @temp b 
               WHERE b.Userid = a.Userid 
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM @temp a
GROUP BY Userid
```

OUTPUT

```
Userid  Permission
  1     admin, download, schedule, test, upload
  2     admin, test, upload
  3     download, upload
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use direct support of [string splitting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt684588.aspx) introduced in SQL Serv 2016 (in case you started using this engine version already of course :) )
STRING_SPLIT returns single column table...